# Kusto - Use .NET SDK to ingest stream data

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am currently trying to upload some data to a Kusto cluster using the C# API. What I am basically trying to perform looks currently like this:

```cs
using (IKustoIngestClient client = KustoIngestFactory.CreateStreamingIngestClient(kustoConnection))
{
    var ingestionProperties = new KustoIngestionProperties()
    {
        DatabaseName = _kustoSettings.DatabaseName,
        TableName = tableName,
        Format = DataSourceFormat.json
    };

    // ms is a Memory Stream
    client.IngestFromStreamAsync(ms, ingestionProperties);
}
```

The problem with the current code or tactics that I see in multiple [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-examples) is that they use `Thread.Sleep` and then check for the result. This is something that in my opinion is not really useful since the application has to know if the operation succeeded or not.

So is there a way for the above code to validate and properly throw an exception in the case of any failure. Cause now despite failing there are no exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some recommended reading:

- [Kusto ingest client library - Best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-best-practices)
- [Tracking Ingestion Status (KustoQueuedIngestClient)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-status#tracking-ingestion-status-kustoqueuedingestclient)

The bottom line:

- Async ingestion has some major advantages over Sync ingestion.
- Tracking each ingestion operation for a heavy load might have significant implications on the ingestion latency and the cluster responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. But the questions is more related on how I can be certain that something has actually arrived to Kusto from the code. The tracking ingestion is using `Thread.Sleep` in every example and I am wondering if there is even a way for to ingest data and be certain that the data has been ingested

Comment: It might make more sense for the application to write to Event Hubs and let ADX to ingest from there.